# How do I send a message from a different section of code from where the new instance of the WebSocket class was created in websocket-sharp C#

Tags: c#, websocket-sharp

This is my first post on Stack Overflow, so please excuse me if my question isn't very clear. To add more context, I want to open a connection to a WebSocket when the connect button is clicked and for a message to be sent from the connection opened by the connect button when the sent button is clicked. The problem is that I can not access the ws variable that I have created in the connect button from the send message button. The code below may give you more of an idea of what I want to do:

```
   private void buttonConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        var ws = new WebSocket(textBoxSocketUrl.Text);

        ws.Connect();
   }

   private void buttonSendMessage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       ws.Send(textBoxMessage.Text);
   }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected, that you can not see `ws` variable, because it was created in another "context". In order to get it, `ws` should be part of your class. Try to change your code to something like this:

```
private WebSocket ws;

private void buttonConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        ws = new WebSocket(textBoxSocketUrl.Text);

        ws.Connect();
   }

   private void buttonSendMessage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       ws.Send(textBoxMessage.Text);
   }
```